# Get output frame rate from AWS elastic transcoder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, transcoding

I've tried the [`get-job`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/get-job.html) method to retrieve information about the frame rate.

But it seems that I can only specify the input frame rate. What I want to do is to set the input frame rate to auto and retrieve the frame rate from the output.

Does anyone know if this is possible or do I have to choose another transcoding service?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Elastic Transcoder, but it takes two steps. You first must retrieve the preset ID used for the job. Then, retrieve that preset to get the frame rate that was used for the transcoding job.

Here are the docs for getting a job:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/get-job.html

And here are the docs for retrieving preset info:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/get-preset.html

Comment: The `get-preset` method only gives you the input settings the job was performed with. In my case, the frame rate will show `auto`. What I need is the actual frame rate of the clip.

Comment: @carcel Have you tried it and it returned `auto`? Because I just did it and it returned frame rate of 15. The input setting was `auto` when I created the job. Try it and see what it actually returns.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `auto` as setting? I've tried it and the preset contains frame rate `auto` not the actual frame rate of the file.

Comment: @carcel I'm positive. I created a job using this PHP class: https://github.com/LPology/ElasticTranscoderPHP which defaults to `auto` if `FrameRate` is not specified. I know that b/c I'm the lib author. I then pulled the default preset with ID# `1351620000001-000060`, which was used for that job. The value in `$response['Preset']['Video']['FrameRate']` is 15, which is the `FrameRate` of output videos for that particular preset. That is how you retrieve the `FrameRate` of the output video when using `auto` for the input `FrameRate` setting.